# Tensorflow variables do not initialise

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to work out why in the two methods below, Method 2 throws an error when I try to initialise a variable in Tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

**Method 1**

This method works fine returning the correct output

```
with tf.variable_scope('layer_1'):
    W1 = tf.get_variable(name="weights1", shape=[3, 10], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(W1))
```

**Method 2**

This method throws an error.

```
with tf.variable_scope('layer_2'):
    W2 = tf.get_variable(tf.zeros(shape=[3, 10], name="weights2"))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(W2))
```

The error message I receive for method 2 is:

```
TypeError: Expected float32, got 'layer_2/' of type 'str' instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (positional) argument to [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) is the `name` of the variable. So your second code is equivalent to

```
tf.get_variable(name=tf.zeros(shape=[3, 10], name="weights2"))
```

Trying to use a `tf.Tensor` as the name of a variable does not work (I'm amazed it does not give an error earlier).

You perhaps want to instead do

```
tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[3, 10]), name="weights2")
```